# PDFBox throws exception: NullReference Exception

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception, pdfbox

pdfbox issue

I used pdfbox to extract text from PDF to my richtextbox.

I don't know what's the problem but there are PDF that are good but there are PDF that throws an exception, the exception is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here's my code:

```
using org.pdfbox.pdmodel;
using org.pdfbox.util;

private void pdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFD = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFD.FileName = "";
    openFD.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
    openFD.Filter = "All PDF Files|*.PDF";
    openFD.Title = "Browse all PDF files";

    if (openFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            pdf_filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFD.Filename);
            PDDocument pdfFile = PDDocument.load(openFD.Filename);

            PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            richtextBox1.Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdfFile);
            textBox1.Text = Path.GetFileName(openFD.Filename);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At which line do you get the exception?

Comment: it seems that pdfFile or pdfStripper are null. At which line does the exception occurs?

Comment: the exception was catch by the catch statement

Comment: What these people want to know is after which line does it jump to the catch?

Comment: If I remove the try and catch statement the exception occurs on this line: pdfRT.Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdfFile);

Comment: Have you debugged this? When the code hits the breakpoint on the line you just giving us, check if all objects in that line are instantiated (pdfRT, pdfStripper and pdfFile)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue using iTextSharp. This was advised by my co-worker, I changed the PDFBox by iTextSharp.

If someone will have the same issue as me here's the working code:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;


private void pdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFD = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFD.FileName = "";
    openFD.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
    openFD.Filter = "All PDF Files|*.PDF";
    openFD.Title = "Browse all PDF files";

    if (openFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            pdf_filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFD.Filename);

            richtextBox1.Text = ReadPdf(openFD.FileName);
            textBox1.Text = Path.GetFileName(openFD.Filename);
        }

        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }

    }
}


private string ReadPdf(string filename)
{

    if (!File.Exists(filename)) return string.Empty;

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);

    string text = string.Empty;

    for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
    {

        text += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page);

    }

    return text;
}
```